# Stream alternative avoid the else part if filter fails

Tags: java, java-stream

I have below scenario, two lists of email objects.
I compare them and if the email is new, I have to create it, if it is existing and it has changes only then I have to update it.
Below is my code, but issue is if the condition "existing is true, but has not changed" false, it being existing email, goes in create new.
Please suggest what part of my code needs modification.

Basically I want to do Create only if it is new, not because the filter failed as the object was exsisting but was not changed.

```
    List<Email> vExistingEmails = pFromExisting.getEmails();
    List<Email> vRequestEmails = pFromPayload.getEmails();

    List<Email> vExistingEmailsList = (null != vRequestEmails && !vRequestEmails.isEmpty())
            ? vRequestEmails.stream()
                    .map(postedEmail -> vExistingEmails.stream()
                            .filter(existingEmail -> isEmailExistAndChanged(postedEmail, existingEmail))
                            .findAny()
                            .map(foundExistingEmail -> updateExistingEmail(foundExistingEmail, postedEmail))
                            .orElse(createEmailfromRequestModel(postedEmail)))
                    .filter(processedEmail -> processedEmail!=null)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            : null;
```

isEmailExistAndChanged --> checks if the email iterated in both list object is same and is unchanged w.r.t any of its attributes.

updateExistingEmail --> if isEmailExistAndChanged returns true, we just update the existing email with updated attribute and return the same.

createEmailfromRequestModel --> if Email is a new one, we want to create a new object and return it.
That is what we were trying to acheive.

Comment: I would use some Map of id to email. Then you can do `computeIfAbsent()`. I didn't scrutinize your code very closely, but I suspect you'd need to throw most of it away if you followed my approach

Comment: I did not wanted to iterate two list in old java way and then either do a create or update. So wanted to do it using streams. I am not finding any easy way to crack it. it two lists have same email object and unchanged then it does not update it, but in the end it executes the else and does a create if nothing matches in the filter.,  that is the problem @Michael

Answer (score 1):

The whole implementation improvement/modification heavily depends on what we can find inside of `isEmailExistAndChanged`, `updateExistingEmail` and `createEmailfromRequestModel` methods. As already suggested in the comments section, I would also vote for modifying the whole structure to `Map<String, Email>` where `String` is the Email's key (assuming it's a String). The further computations become the way easier to write.

---

Assuming it remains a black-box, the only improvement you can achieve is the maintainability through:

- Making the whole thing more readable, i.e. avoid ternary operators and use `Optional` instead. This enables comfortable method chaining and there is no longer need the searching for the `?` after a condition and `:` somewhere in the end of the Stream itself (the shorter alternative should come first in case of ternary operator usage, IMHO).
- Checking `!vRequestEmails.isEmpty()` before using Stream is redundant. Stream API *does* handle that. There is no additional computation cost.
- Not returning `null` and return an empty list instead. The idea behind this design that an empty list is valid, can be processed and `null` checks can be omitted. Again, there is no additional computation cost.

**Java 8**

```
List<Email> vExistingEmailsList = Optional.ofNullable(vRequestEmails)
    .map(Collection::stream)
    .orElse(Stream.empty())
    .map(email -> vExistingEmails.stream()
         .filter(existingEmail -> isEmailExistAndChanged(email, existingEmail))
         .findAny()
         .map(foundExistingEmail -> updateExistingEmail(foundExistingEmail, email))
         .orElse(createEmailfromRequestModel(email)))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Java 9+**

You can simplify the beginning using [`Optional#stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--). Just `flatmap` the whole thing, though:

```
List<Email> vExistingEmailsList2 = Optional.ofNullable(vRequestEmails)
    .stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .map(email -> ... )
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikolas, isEmailExistAndChanged --> checks if the email iterated in both list object is same and is unchanged w.r.t any of its attributes.

updateExistingEmail --> if isEmailExistAndChanged returns true, we just update the existing email with updated attribute and return the same.

createEmailfromRequestModel --> if Email is a new one, we want to create a new object and return it.
That is what we were trying to achieve. is that achieveable, I am trying to do upsert in the updateExistingEmail now and in orElse will return null. is that better? getEmails() return list hence no map

Comment: It's pretty clear what it does judging from the method names. The point is whether it performs an additional logics or a simple transformation. If so, would you provide their implementations so my answer becomes more focused?